# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property to an Enum type entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this .Net Core 3.1 web project that has an entity (`Process`) reference to an Enum type entity (`Status`). It is setup this way to be used by the stateless workflow to handle change of process status in the program. At runtime, it failed at this line with the above exception message:

```
processes = await _dbContext.Process.ToListAsync();
```

The complete exception message:

```
'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Process.Status' of type 'Status'. 
Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'
```

Below are the model and dbcontext codes:

```
public enum StatusID : int
{
    [Display(Name = "Draft")]
    Draft = 1,

    [Display(Name ="In Review")]
    InReview = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Approved")]
    Inactive = 3
}

[Table("Status", Schema = "Industrial")]
public class Status
{
    private Status() { }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public StatusID StatusID { get; private set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

[Table("Process", Schema = "Industrial")]
public partial class Process
{
    [Key]
    public int ProcessID { get; set; }
    public StatusID StatusID { get; set; } = StatusID.Draft;
    [ForeignKey("StatusID")]
    public virtual Status Status { get; private set; }
}

public class DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Process> Process { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
        modelBuilder.Entity<Status>().HasNoKey().Property(c => c.StatusID)
         .HasConversion(
             v => v.ToString().ToLowerInvariant(),
             v => (StatusID)Enum.Parse(typeof(StatusID), v, true)
         )
         .HasColumnName("GeneralName")
         .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

I searched for other posts here, many suggested putting up navigation definition in OnModelCreating method in the DbContext, I've tried a few variants of that, all failed. Here are a couple that I tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Process>()
                .HasOne("Status", "Status")
                .WithOne("Status");


modelBuilder.Entity<Process>()
                    .HasOne(p => p.Status)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey<Status>(m => m.StatusID)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: Why do you have `Key` attribute on `Status.StatusID` and `HasNoKey` call for `Entity<Status>`?

Comment: The `Key` on `Status` is not database generated as annotated, the `HasNoKey` is in part for at runtime to convert `StatusID` from DB to the Enum type. Both of these are  for the stateless workflow to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of this problem, it is because my database table generation script has an error in the foreign key creation statement, it should be as below:

```
ALTER TABLE [Industrial].[Process]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Process_Status_StatusID] FOREIGN KEY([StatusID])
REFERENCES [Industrial].[Status] ([StatusID])
```

what I had was `[FK_Process_Status]`, instead of `[FK_Process_Status_StatusID]`

This is in Microsoft SQL Server.